# Mapping violation of DRY principle? How to separate layers in ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am the lone developer on a new ASP.NET MVC project, so my ability to discuss design with peers is limited. I'd like to ensure that any change to my app in the future is confined to the layer being changed, so that the whole app doesn't have to change at once.

I'm planning to have 3 layers, each in it's own project, consisting of data layer, service/business layer, and presentation layer.

My data layer will use Entity Framework with a generic repository. This layer will return Entity types from the repo methods.

My service/business layer will be thin, but I wanted a nice separate place for business logic down the road. In the beginning, it will be nothing more than service classes for each of the major areas of my app. ie EmployeeService provides CRUD methods related to Employees that call upon the data layer. At some point, I may replace it with a Web API service layer and serve many clients.

My presentation layer will be ASP.NET MVC, with ViewModels and strongly typed views. Down the road, there may be additional clients.

I'm most interested in the communication between layers and project structure. My initial thoughts were to map data layer Entities to service layer Business Objs/Domain Objs or DTOs using AutoMapper, then mapping again to ViewModels in presentation. The mappings in the beginning would be mostly 1:1 though, so it feels redundant.

Is it a violation of DRY to have a DTO that is the same as the Entity class? That's the only way I know how to decouple from my database structure. Ideally, if I make a database change, I want to only have to change the Entities and the mappings. ie, I totally rearrange how I'm storing something and I have all new entity classes/relationships... I'd like to map the new data implementation back to the same DTO and higher layers never know.

The same repetition feeling comes up when mapping from service layer to presentation layer. My DTOs will get mapped to ViewModels. It's mostly the same stuff, but my thinking was that ViewModels also contain UI implementation details like sort fields and UI specific types like SelectListItem.

So is this actually repetition or does it just feel repetitive? Is there another way to accomplish my aim of isolating changes in layers? I'd like to be able to change or replace presentation, service or data layer with relative ease.

Comment: Though this question is well thought out, it is still likely to encounter negative responses due to the focus of this site.  Unfortunately, opinionated questions such as this aren't really a good fit, because the site structure focuses on *concrete* problems with *verifiable* answers.  In this case, you could receive multiple answers which contradict each other but would be equally correct, which makes this a question more suited to a discussion forum.

Comment: So should I just delete this? I don't have anyone to discuss such things with, so this seemed like a place I could invite that discussion.

Comment: the site offers [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/), you might find people willing to discuss options there;  I just wanted to give you some feedback on why you might see negative responses.  If you leave the question open, it will likely be put on hold anyway.

Comment: I've reworded to try to ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend finding a solid (and SOLID) open source MVC project and follow that pattern.  No need to re-invent the wheel -- .NET MVC is robust and there are plenty of projects that follow SOLID principles.

Take a look at [NopCommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com/), you can get the source code and you will see a well-architected app that answers many of your questions

Comment: So I've looked through the nopCommerce app, and it's pretty similar to what I was planning. Similarly, it's MVC at presentation, using a service layer to retrieve data from Repositories on top of Entity Framework.

But it has domain classes for data, which are also entity classes and so reflect the physical database. These domain objects are returned by the service layer and mapped to models in the controller, so that means the presentation layer is still coupled to the database structure does it not? A change to how I store something means I'd have to change presentation. :\

Comment: The Repositories are where you would decouple the database from the front-end.  If you have a repo method that said "GetCustomers" and that returned a model, you could populate that model anyway you wanted to and your presentation layer wouldn't care or know.  Separation of concerns...

Comment: So there still has to be mapping in there somewhere, correct? From the entity classes to the domain/business/dto classes that the repo method returns.

Comment: Yes.  That is the purpose of a domain layer -- it aggregates/maps/transforms disparate data into something meaningful for the presentation layer.

Comment: Is there not also a mapping from domain objects to ViewModels? Like, say I have a view with a SelectList, perhaps my ViewModel has a collection of SelectListItem. SelectListItem is pretty specific to that presentation, so I don't think it makes sense to have SelectListItem type in my domain object. So I'd have to have a mapping from domain object to ViewModel right?

That's what I thought I was doing in my plan to map Entities to DTOs (effectively domain objects, no?), then DTOs to ViewModels.

Comment: Unless I'm not following it correctly, there is no mapping of Entity objects to Domain objects in the NopCommerce app. Their Domain classes are entities, and they're passed all the way up to Presentation and then mapped to ViewModels.

Comment: Probably true, I haven't looked at that code in awhile.  Many MVC apps use the ViewModels as a de-facto domain layer, and I think this is what NopCommerce does.